# The number of send data every second less than params, How to send more data every second?

Tags: c, alsa

this funtion is to play audio data use alsa libs in linux.but have a question,the send data is less than set params.

```
    int main()   
    {   
    int rc = 0;  
    snd_pcm_t *handle;  
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;  
    int dir = 0;  
    char *buffer;  
    int size=0;  
    int val = 0;  
    int frames = 0;  
    int min,max;  
    int period_time;  
    snd_pcm_sframes_t delay,buffer_size,period_size,avail; 
    //through kill signal to statistics the number of send data
    signal(SIGUSR1, sigproc_status);  
    rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle,"default",SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK,0);  
    if(rc < 0)  
    {  
            printf("unable to open pcm device\n");  
            return -1;  
    }  
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);  
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle,params);  
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle,params,SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);  
    //set 16bit
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle,params,SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    //set two channels
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle,params,2);  
    val = 44100;  
    //set rate is 44.1k
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle,params,&val,&dir);
    rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle,params);  
    if(rc < 0)  
    {  
            printf("unable to set params\n");  
            return -1;  
    }  
    snd_pcm_hw_params_current(handle,params);
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &period_time,NULL);  
    frames = 32;  
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params,&frames,&dir); 
    size = frames*4;   
    buffer = (char *)malloc(size);   
    while(1)  
    {    
            len = len + size;  
            rc = snd_pcm_writei(handle,buffer,frames);    
            if(rc == -EPIPE)    
            {     
                    printf("underrun occur\n");   
                    snd_pcm_prepare(handle);   
            }   
    }  
    }
```

the period_time=21333 frames=940,so (1000000/21333)*940*4=176252bytes
but params is 44100*4=176400bytes
so we need to discard some bytes every sencond.
how to send more bytes?

Comment: What is the value of `val` after `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near()` has returned?

Comment: val return 44100

Comment: Show the contents of `/proc/asound/cardX/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params` while it's playing.

Comment: /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params is different with set params

Comment: cat hw_params access:MMAP_INTERLEAVED format:S32_LE subformat:STD channels2 rate:48000(48000/1) period_size:1024 buffer_size:8192

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default configuration with `dmix`, which requires resampling from 44.1 kHz to 48 kHz. ALSA's internal resampler always works on entire periods, so the period size you are forced to use is 1024*44.1/48 = 940 (rounded down).

To force a period size of 941, use a frequency of 44110.

If you want to avoid resampling, if possible, open the device `plughw:0` instead of `default`, but then you lose the multi-client mixing capability. (And then you should configure buffer/period sizes according to your requirements.)